# Cannot adjust height of iframe

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, jquery, custom-controller

I am trying to adjust the height of an iframe to **200px** via Jquery. However I'm not able to do so.

Below is my code

```
$(function(){ 
alert('Hi');
$('iframe[title=TestPageResult]').css("height", 200);
});
```

I have also tried the below too without any effect

```
<style>
.frameHeight {
height: 100px !important;
}
</style>
<script>
 $(function(){ 
  alert('Hi');
  $('iframe[title=TestPageResult]').addClass('frameHeight');
 });
```

As a bit of context, theres no other unique selector in the iframe(loaded externally by server) other than the attribute **"title"**.

On doing

```
console.log($('iframe[title=TestPageResult]'));
```

I got the result

```
<iframe frameborder="no" height="300px" id="0660Y000004tr0j" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="0660Y000004tr0j" scrolling="no" title="TestPageResult" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Kindly help me to figure out the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to modify an iframe outside of your own document?

Comment: Nopes. The iframe is indicating a section in the page layout with an embedded VF page. Inorder for the VF page to render correctly in Lightning Experience mode, I had to set the height of the section to 300px in page layout. This however resulted in a lot of blank space when viewed in 'Classic' mode. Hence the jquery hack.

Comment: that's "outside" of your own document. Sandbox security set on the iframe will restrict your ability to access the iframe from the child page. There's an idea regarding allowing dynamic resizing, but as far as I know, it isn't a thing yet. You'll have to deal with the extra space.

Comment: I am not getting it properly. If so, then may I know how I got the console output when tried to select the iframe?

Comment: If yur in the frame you can't haz resize

Comment: @sfdcfox, How about if OP tries to set the height of the div(or whatever container) and change its height through JS? That might work right?